If the TextField is in the Toolbar, the keyboard does not disappear when using BackSwipe
I made a custom search, which is in the toolbar, at the .principal position (using iOS 16).
func navigationBarWithSearch(searchText: Binding<String>, keyboardAppearanceDelay: Double = 0.0, cancelAction: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                ToolbarSearchView(
                    keyboardAppearanceDelay: keyboardAppearanceDelay,
                    text: searchText,
                    cancelAction: cancelAction
                )
            }
        }
    }

The textField itself is UIViewRepresentable. And everything works fine, except for one thing. It has to do with the fact that when the keyboard is shown on the screen and I do a BackSwipe to the previous screen, the keyboard doesn't disappear (as it should).
I debugged the appearance of the keyboard and saw that when I do BackSwipe, NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification) is triggered. And then, the textFieldDidBeginEditing method is abruptly triggered (and because of that, the keyboard doesn't disappear until I close the screen all the way).
I thought that maybe the becomeFirstResponder() method was being triggered again, but no.
I also tried broadcasting a method to force hiding the keyboard, but that didn't help either.
Also, later on, I decided to test the operation of this textField outside the NavigationBar, and the keyboard worked fine, just as expected. It disappeared when using BackSwipe.
As far as I understand, the problem lies in the use of textField in NavigationBar, but how to solve it ?
You can see here that the keyboard twitches during BackSwipe - that's it disappearing and reappearing. And you can see that when I pull the screen, the keyboard stays in place and does not hide.
I tried to solve the problem, debugging the keyboard appearing and disappearing, trying to use methods to make the keyboard disappear forcibly, but nothing worked. I checked textField operation separately from NavigationBar (and found out that such strange keyboard behavior only happens when textField is in NavigationBar).
I expect the keyboard to fade smoothly when using BackSwipe, as it does if I use other textFields outside the NavigationBar

Why do you use a UIKit view and not a TextField ?

@PtitXav I use UIKit because I need more customization and control for my TextField, which SwiftUI can't provide yet. But it makes no difference at all whether it is UIKit or SwiftUI View, the problem occurs even in an empty project.
I tried yesterday running an empty project that has navigation and two screens. On the second screen, I also put a TextField in place of the .principal (without using UIViewRepresentable already) and the keyboard problem was the same when using BackSwipe to the past screen
